# How to write an ersatz of solver program in C?

Tags: c, solver

1) I want to create a (ersatz of) solver, where a simple expression such as :

```
Revenue = Cost * (1 + GrossMargin)
```

would lead to 3 questions to the user :

- Revenue ?
- Cost ?
- GrossMargin ?

the user being asked to answer 2 out of those 3 questions, and the program calculating the third.

This is my (utter newbie) attempt :

```
//
//  main.c
//  LearningC
//  Created by ThG on 19/10/13
//

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Variables
    float Cost = 0;
    float GrossMargin = 0;
    float Revenue = 0;

    // Ask the User
    printf("What is your Revenue ? : ");
    scanf("%f", &Revenue);
    printf("What is your cost ? : ");
    scanf("%f", &Cost);
        printf("What is your Gross Margin goal ? : ");
    scanf("%f", &GrossMargin);

    // Equation
    Revenue = Cost * (1 + GrossMargin);

    // Nested ifs or expressions "Solver"
    if (Revenue == 0)
    {
        printf("Your Revenue should be : %.2f $ * (1 + %.2f) = %.2f $\n", Cost, GrossMargin, Revenue);
    }
        else
        {
            if (Cost == 0)
                printf("Your Cost should not be higher than : %.2f $ / (1 + %.2f) = %.2f $\n", Revenue, GrossMargin, Cost);
            else
                printf("Your GrossMargin is : %.2f $ / %.2f -1 = %.2f $\n", Revenue, Cost, GrossMargin);
        }

    return 0;    
}
```

Of course, this failed miserably (btw, what does (lldb mean ?). How should I proceed ?

I hope this question is not irrelevant in StackOverflow's context. Should I precise that this is not homework (I am retired…) ?

2) I used to have on my (Jurassic) Palm Pilot a remarkable solver program called MathPad (by Rick Huebner, see http://www.palmspot.com/software/detail/ps52a_98295.html), maybe written in C.

Do you know if anything equivalent has been developed and maintained ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program uses this calculation:

```
Revenue = Cost * (1 + GrossMargin);
```

If `Revenue` was entered as zero, it would be correct. But guess what happens if you intended to calculate `Cost` and entered it as zero while you entered valid values for `Revenue` and `Cost`. As you said, it will fail miserably.

The simplest solution is to check which of the entered quantities is zero and calculate it accordingly. Something like this:

```
if(Revenue == 0)
    Revenue = Cost * (1 + GrossMargin);
else if(Cost == 0)
    Cost = Revenue / (1+GrossMargin);
else
    GrossMargin = (Revenue-Cost)/Cost;
```

Then display your values.

Comment: It works, of course (had a little problem as to where to put the curly braces ...). Thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry to bother you again... Is it necessary to write down the 3 different expressions ? After all, it is supposed to be a (dumb) solver ... Would it be possible to present the expression in the more general form : Revenue - Cost * (1 + GrossMargin) = 0 and have the 3 conditions tested successively ? Thanks again

Comment: @ThG You are right. It is a dumb solver. But computers are dumb too. Given a formula `Revenue = Cost * (1 + GrossMargin)` we can derive the formulation for other quantities but a computer can't. It must be told explicitly what you want. That said, it is possible to program in such a way that given just `Revenue = Cost * (1 + GrossMargin)`, the computer can derive a correct expression to calculate the missing quantity. But, the effort of the `means` would be costlier than the `goal`.